# How does a method of a map apply to each element when using something like .index of

Tags: javascript

I saw an answer online with something like this:

```
myArray.map(e=>e.id).indexOf("something")
```

but it didnt really make sense to me, as it seems like this "." operatore is going to be applied after the map function is executed? I guess it gets applied to every iteration of the map function, however whats confusing me is, isnt "indexOf" a method of the array object? Does the map function return an array? Also how is it being applied to every index, does the map function return after every iteration and run again?

Comment: The `map` method on an `Array` will loop through all your items, call the method you passed into it for each item and then assign the returned value to the same index of a _new_ array. Once it has done that, `map` will return that _new_ `Array` (not the original). Then you can use `indexOf` on _that array_ to find the index of that item in your "new" array (this "new" array maps one to one to your "old" one, so if the index is found, the original object will be at the same index).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the map function returns an array. It can extract data from each element of a given array then stores it in a new array and finally returns that array. The indexOf function is used to get the index of some value in an array. So in this case it returns the index of "something" from the array that gets returned from the map function. It is only executed once, after the map function returned the new array.

Example:

```js
const fruits = [
    {
        name: "Apple",
        id: 1
    },{
        name: "Pear",
        id: 2
    },{
        name: "Banana",
        id: 3
    }
];

const names = fruits.map(fruit=>fruit.name) // => ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana"]
names.indexOf("Pear") // => 1
```

Comment: If you are going into the weeds, might as well point to the `.findIndex` method as well, as it does both it one go: `fruits.findIndex(f => f.name === "Pear")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys, I guess the key is that the map function returns a new  array with the element in the lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

When you map an array in JS, it gives a function as input (let's say `mapperFunc`). `mapperFunc` is executed on every element in that array. Each array element is passed to `mapperFunc` as its input and the function output will return as the result. All those results together will make up a new array which would be the result of the mapping:

```
myArray.map(function mapperFunc(arrayElement) {
    return mappedElement;// do some calcuations
});
```

you can concise the above code using lambda:

```
myArray.map((arrayElement) => mappedElement);
```

suppose that you have an array of numbers and you want to multiply all its elements by 2:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(elem => elem * 2);// output will be [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

you can apply any function that is applicable to an array on the `map` result. For example, `indexOf`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(elem => elem * 2).indexOf(6); // will return 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your implementation is as follows

> myArray.map(e=>e.id).indexOf("something")

First of all, you are using `myArray` which is a JS array.

The array has different instances/prototype methods among them `map` is one.

so, we can do

> myArray.map(callback) => returns new Array

**callback** = function to be executed in each element of an array
and each callback should return the value. The same value is appended to a new
array each time it is called. Finally, a new array is returned.

so, myArray.map(callback) => returns new Array (let's say array2)
Then, it becomes

```
 array2.indexOf("something");
```

Since indexOf is also the instance/prototype method of JS array. We can now use it as well. This time it returns -1 if not found and if element is found within an array then index of that element is returned.

Here, JS performs the operation from left to right. First executing the map and then indexOf method.
I think all the detail explanation are already covered in the above answers